# directories with special in batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've got a batch file I created a while ago which simply takes an image, converts it to a 256 * 256 icon file (using imagemagick) and sets it as the image directories icon.

Pretty simple stuff but I do have one problem which I just cannot seem to get my head around, no matter what I read about it. If a directory has any kind of special character it won't work, an annoyance since it's used mainly on directories with brackets in them.

Anyone care to explain what I'm doing wrong? I've never worked in batch files before so realize I'm far from good.

```
@ECHO off
%~d1
cd %~p1

set str=%~d1%~p1

If NOT exist "%str%Folder Options" (
   md "%str%Folder Options"
)

If exist "%str%Folder Options\folder.ico" (
   del %str%Folder Options\folder.ico
)

convert %1 -resize 256x256 "%str%Folder Options\folder_256.png"
convert "%str%Folder Options\folder_256.png" -gravity center -background none -extent 256x256 "%str%Folder Options\folder_256x256_alpha.png"

convert "%str%Folder Options\folder_256x256_alpha.png" "%str%Folder Options\folder.ico"

del "%str%Folder Options\folder_256.png"
del "%str%Folder Options\folder_256x256_alpha.png"

If exist "%str%desktop.ini" (
   Attrib -S -H "%str%desktop.ini"
   del "%str%desktop.ini"
)

ECHO Creating desktop.ini
(
   ECHO [.ShellClassInfo]
   ECHO IconFile=Folder Options\folder.ico
   ECHO IconIndex=0
) >"%str%desktop.ini"

Attrib +H "%str%Folder Options"
Attrib +H +S "%str%desktop.ini"
Attrib +R "%str:~0,-1%"
```

Comment: What kind of special characters? What part of the script fails? What error do you get? Have you tried debugging the script to determine exactly what command causes the failure?

Comment: Special characters are anything that aren't a space, letter or number. While debugging it seems that it fails right at the start while checking whether files and directories exist. Without those lines the script runs fine.

Comment: Note that the `del` command's parameter is not enclosed in quotes. Could that be it?

Comment: Moar quotes.  `set "str=%~d1%~p1"`

Comment: It was the del command parameter not being enclosed in quotes >_> Thanks for noticing that. All working now!